# How to install Boost from source

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to install the Boost C++ from source.

I first tried using yum to install them in (Amazon Linux AMI) but it installed a version that is too old. I need at least version 1.54

So I tried to follow the instructions here:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Once I downloaded the source, I tried symlinking the header files to /usr/include:

```
ln -s /root/boost_1_70_0/boost /usr/include/boost
```

Then I followed the instructions to try to build:

```
cd /root/boost_1_70_0
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 install
```

Then when I try to compile my program that needs boost libraries (happens to be OSRM), I get this error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so', needed by `osrm-components'.  Stop.
```

So it seems somehow I need to build the boost `.so` files to go in `/usr/lib64`. But how do I do that?

Comment: I'm afraid that you will need to spend some period of time learning the native packaging infrastructure for your Linux distribution (rpm or deb), so you can do this correctly by creating a package that can be installed by your Linux distribution's package manager. Otherwise, unsolicited overwriting, like this, of system-installed libraries with custom-built, different version of a core system library, without leveraging the dependency-checking safety net of your Linux distribution's package manager, is a rather efficient way to end up with an unbootable brick.

Comment: May I suggest you take a look at conan?
https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you've already built the boost `.so` files but I don't know where. It normally tries to install them in `/usr/local`, see section 5.1 of the instructions you referenced.

You may be able to find them with `locate`, e.g.:

```
 locate boost
```

Otherwise, you can call `./bootstrap.sh` with a prefix indicating *where* you want it to build the libraries, e.g.:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/root/boost_1_70_0/stage
./b2 install
```

You can then copy the `.so` files together with with their symbolic links to `/usr/lib64`, e.g.:

```
cd /usr/lib64
rm -fr libboost*
cp -a /root/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib/libboost* .
chmod a+x libboost*
```

Note: the line `rm -fr libboost*` in `/usr/lib64` is to remove the *very* old version of boost that you installed with `yum`.